# Give all the complex solutions of $sinz+cosz=i \sqrt{2}$ being $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I have to give all the complex solutions of the following equation: $\space$

$sinz+cosz=i \sqrt{2}$ $\space $$\space $$\space $being$\space $$\space $ $z\in \mathbb{C}$

---

This is what I have done: $\space$

As I know that $sinz=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $cosz=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, we have: $\space$

$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}+\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=i\sqrt{2} \to \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} \frac{(-2i)}{(-2i)}+\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=i\sqrt{2} \to \frac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})(-2i)}{4}+\frac{(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})2}{4}=\frac{4\sqrt{2}i}{4} \to (e^{iz}-e^{-iz})(-2i)+(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})2-4\sqrt{2}i=0 \to (-2i)e^{2iz}-(-2i)+2e^{2iz}+2-4\sqrt{2}e^{iz}i=0 \to (2-2i)e^{2iz}-4\sqrt{2}ie^{iz}+2+2i=0$ $\space$

Solving that, I reach to the conclusion that $e^{iz}=\frac{-(2+-\sqrt{2})+(2+-\sqrt{2})i}{2}$ $\space$

And know, $iz=log(\frac{-(2+\sqrt{2})+(2+\sqrt{2})i}{2})$ and $iz=log(\frac{-(2-\sqrt{2})+(2-\sqrt{2})i}{2})$ $\space$

I don't know if I'm doing well the exercise... Am I? Or how can I do it? I don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution:

Recast the LHS using the $R,\alpha$ form to get:

$\sqrt 2\sin(z + \frac{\pi}{4}) = i\sqrt 2$

$\sin(z + \frac{\pi}{4}) = i$

Now note that $\sin ix = i\sinh x$, so you know that $\sin (i\sinh^{-1} 1) = i$

You then have $\sin(z + \frac{\pi}{4}) = \sin (i\sinh^{-1} 1)$

giving $z + \frac{\pi}{4} = 2k\pi + i\sinh^{-1} 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

And the general solution is $z = \frac {\pi}4(8k-1) + i\sinh^{-1} 1 = \frac {\pi}4(8k-1) + i\ln(1+\sqrt 2), k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: why did you put $\sqrt{2}sin(z)+\frac{\pi}{4}$ instead of $sinz+cosz$ ? Are them equal?

Comment: Yes (but you wrote the brackets wrongly, and that's important), it's a handy technique both for elementary trig as well as more advanced stuff like this. Please see: https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php